# removing a DOM object from an array of DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-mobile

if i use this `$("div:jqmData(role='page')")` it will return me the array of pages in my `DOM` object. But jquerymobile creates a default blank page which doesnt have any ID so i cant actually get it by its ID. instead i use `$("div:jqmData(role='page')").get(0)` to get the first DOM object representing the default Page jquery created.

but if i use `$("div:jqmData(role='page')").get(0).remove()` it doesnt remove the page, but it returns errors.

can anyone teach me on how to remove that DOM? thanks!

Comment: _"it will return me the array of pages"_ - Correction: it will return a jQuery object with your pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.remove()` is a jQuery method, so you need a jQuery object to call it on. `.get` returns a DOM element though. Use [`.eq` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead to get the element as jQuery object:

```
$("div:jqmData(role='page')").eq(0).remove()
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) function returns the DOM element itself, so you won't be able to chain jQuery functions (such as `.remove()`) after it. If you need to do that, use the [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method which returns that single DOM element wrapped in a jQuery object, allowing you to chain.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `.get()` returns the underlying DOM element, **not** the jQuery object. You can use `.eq()` to access the jQuery object at a specific index.

So this should work:

```
$("div:jqmData(role='page')").eq(0).remove()
```